# why power steering fluid bubbling causing steam with a new pump

Tags: steering, power

i have a ford taurus- new pump put on 4 days ago. fluid bubbling started today causing steam when car is turned off.
what needs to be done?  is it safe to drive?

Comment: While this might not be good for the power steering system, it isn't particularly dangerous to you physically. If the power steering fails, the steering will become a lot heavier, making quick precise maneuvers more difficult, but the steering will still fundamentally work.

Comment: Take it back to the mechanic and get them to fix it properly. They must have made some sort of mistake, used the wrong fluid or used one that is contaminated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bleed the system of all air before starting the vehicle. Especially on ford's, you can destroy that new pump instantly.

The proper installation is as follows:

1. Install new pump onto vehicle and connect lines
2. Fill pump full of new power steering fluid
3. Roll power steering pully with a wrench or by hand and add fluid accordingly, do this by hand until you see very few air bubbles.
4. Start vehicle, add fluid until at the cold line
5. Turn steering wheel hard left and hard right until no air bubbles are seen and noise is quiet.
6. Fill to slightly below max hot with vehicle OFF.

Ford PS pumps are the worst.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to replace your power steering fluid. It must have absorbed water. I've never heard of this before, but it seems plausible.